# Is there a query to get the current DB2 IBM Server restart time/uptime?

Tags: db2

I’m used to working with MS SQL and I’m looking for the DB2 equivalent to:

SELECT sqlserver_start_time
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info

I’m expecting to run something like

SELECT CURRENT SERVER START TIME
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

And get a result back like:

CURRENTSERVERSTARTTIME
07-25-2021 23:59:59.000

Can it be done, and does it make sense in an IBM DB2 environment?

Comment: Add your platform and version of Db2 to your question.

Comment: For Db2-servers that run on Linux/Unix/Windows only, if your connecting account has correct authorization, run `SELECT DB2START_TIME FROM TABLE (MON_GET_INSTANCE(-2))`